# convert textareas string value to JavaScript array separated by new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, newline

I have a `textarea` where the user can write up to 1000 characters. I need to get the `jQuery('#textarea').val()` and create an array where each item is a line of the `textarea`'s value. That means:

> This is a nice line inside the textarea.
>   This is another line.
>   (let's asume this line is empty - it should be ignored).
>   Someone left more than 2 new lines above.

Should be converted to a JavaScript array:

```
var texts = [];
text[0] = 'This is a nice line inside the textarea.';
text[1] = 'This is another line.';
text[2] = 'Someone left more than 2 new lines above.';
```

That way they can be easily [imploded](http://phpjs.org/functions/implode:430) for to querystring (this is the qs format required by the provider):

```
example.com/process.php?q=["This is a nice line inside the textarea.","This is another line.","Someone left more than 2 new lines above."]
```

I tried both the [phpjs `explode()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/explode:396) and `string.split("\n")` approaches but they doesn't take care of the extra new lines (aka line breakes). Any ideas?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, maybe try splitting it and then feeding the split bits into an array?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock i just updated the post with some info. I tried that with phpjs explode(), but it doesn't take care of the extra lines (if any) issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`String.prototype.split()` is sweet.

```
var lines = $('#mytextarea').val().split(/\n/);
var texts = [];
for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  // only push this line if it contains a non whitespace character.
  if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
    texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
  }
}
```

Note that `String.prototype.split` is not supported on all platforms, so jQuery provides `$.split()` instead.  It simply trims whitespace around the ends of a string.

```
$.trim(" asd  \n") // "asd"
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/p9krF/1/

Comment: just one thing... one extra enter is allowed, two aren't (2 or more should be converted to one). any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this snippet do that?  If a line contains only whitespace it's ignored.

Comment: yes, but you may have up to 1 of those. this is handy for paragraphs separation.

Answer (score 7):

Use `split` function:

```
var arrayOfLines = $("#input").val().split("\n");
```

Comment: should be `.split(/\n/)`

Answer (score 3):

```
var split = $('#textarea').val().split('\n');
var lines = [];
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    if (split[i]) lines.push(split[i]);
return lines;
```

Comment: worked and takes care of the extra spaces, thanks! just one thing, the "int" should be removed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var lines = [];
$.each($('textarea').val().split(/\n/), function(i, line){
   if(line && line.length){
      lines.push(line);
   }
});
```

Comment: What is `.each` supposed to add? I mean, you're iterating over an array, pushing each element to a new array, and not using the original array. It doesn't look very useful.

Comment: I think now it makes senses, isn't it?

Comment: It does :) Though the `line` check is not necessary; you never get `null` or `undefined`.