# AngularJS & jQuery: Splitting textarea into multiple textareas

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

For a project I'm working on, we want to create an offer module where users can generate an offer from dynamic values. This module has a preview in html and can be downloaded as an pdf version, which is sent to a customer.

A html page is generated with all the data provided. This is done with `ng-model` in the view. Next we simulate multiple pages with jQuery by checking for each element if it is outside a page (each page has a min and max-height of 29,7cm). This functionality is already fixed, so we know this works.

The problem is that we want to check, when a user types in the `textarea`, if the textarea flows outside the page and if so, we want to cut the `textarea` where the overflow is happening and create a new `textarea` with jQuery and fill it with the remaining characters with `ng-model`.

We've looked into splitting all characters into an array, but no luck so far with incorporating this into the `ng-model`. [First approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299604/javascript-convert-textarea-into-an-array/), [Second approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479053/convert-textarea-value-to-javascript-array-separated-by-new-lines)

So the question is, is it possible to check if the overflow happens and if so, create a new textarea with the same `ng-model`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this text that is overflowing all part of one property?  If so I would simple create a directive that handles the visuals for you.  Also consider using the content-editable attribute on a div instead of the textarea.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by part of one property? This is the structure of the textarea: <textarea rows="1" ng-model="offer.openingParagraph" id="offerOpeningParagraph" ng-trim="false">. We will be looking into content-editable attribute, thank you for the tip!

Comment: What about the text area on the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I have created a base sample how to track the overflow and append new textarea .

Check the Fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/88TzF/559/**

> ```
> app = angular.module('myApp', []);
>
>
> app.directive("scrolls", function ($window) {
> return {
>   restrict : 'C',
>   link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
>
>   console.log(element);
>     angular.element(element).bind("scroll", function() {
>     console.log(this.scrollTop);
>     var newarea = angular.element(document.getElementById('newarea'));
>          if(this.scrollTop > 0 )
>          {
>
>           var appendTextbox= '<textarea width="200px" class="scrolls"  style="height:130px;overflow-y:scroll "></textarea>';
>            newarea.append(appendTextbox);
>            var childrens = newarea.children();
>            var  textList = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('scrolls'));
>
>            var tofocus = textList[textList.length-1];
>            console.dir(textList.length);
>            angular.element(tofocus).attr('autofocus','true');
>
>          }
>     });
>     }
> }; });
> ```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a bunch, now we can try this :)